# mod_rewrite save http_referer

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-referer

Could you please help me, I want to put .htaccess file into "/fonts/" folder and save all referes for font files (svg, woff, otf, ttf, eot) for example with save_referer.php.
I just need htaccess code to pass HTTP_REFERER to php file. Thats all.
How can I do it?
Please, help me.

Unfortunately, I didn't find right solution on the internet.

Comment: I need to find out referering domain=)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%{HTTP_REFERER}` server variable when reconstructing the URL you are redirecting to:

```
    RewriteRule ^/fonts/$ http://example.com/save_referer.php?referer=%{HTTP_REFERER}
```

*disclaimer: not tested (but this should get you on the right track)*